# Nginx server doesn't load on Firefox and safari

Tags: nginx

So I recently added ssl using LetsEncrypt to my nginx server and for some reason It just doesn't work when I try using firefox or safari on my mac/iphone and on my windows pc it works fine on chrome? I don't see where I have gone, below is the file for my website which is in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled:

```
server {
        server_name www.domain.net;

        location /static {
                alias /home/user/Flask-Python-Website/website/static;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
                include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }



    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.domain.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.domain.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = www.domain.net) {
        return 301 $scheme://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name www.domain.net;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

When I try with Firefox on www.domain.net I get this error: **"The page isn't redirecting properly"**. If I try domain.net then I get a **404 error**. On my iphone/mac safari I just the same error for domain.net and for www.domain.net I get **"Safari cannot open the page because too many redirects occurred"**. If I try either with the _-[https://](https://__) prefix then they work (except for https://example.com on safari as that brings up a "__This connection is not private" message), I need them to work without having to input the https:// prefix.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your redirect is an infinite loop - it redirects the browser to the same page (and protocol) that it is currently on:

```
if ($host = www.domain.net) {
    return 301 $scheme://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot
```

Also, since the `server_name` line already specifies the domain "www.domain.net", there is no need to check for the host.

Your second server block should look like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name www.domain.net;

    # redirect to https version of this page
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```